# js fails to incorporate into php page

Tags: javascript, php, show-hide

I have the following js code:

```
<style>
<!--
body
{
font-family: "century schoolbook", serif;
font-size: 20px;
}
.hidden
{
display: none;
color: #000;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
.unhide
{
display: block;
color: #000;
}
a.unhide
{
text-decoration: none;
}
a.unhide:hover
{
text-decoration: underline;
}
.unhide:hover
{
background: #FFE5B4;
padding: 3px 8px;
display: table-row;
transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhide' : 'hidden';
}
}
</script>

...
<div class="conBoxcities">
<class id="info">
<a href="javascript:unhide('cityname');" class="unhide">
This is really a js link with a city name. Clicking brings down information about 
that city.
</a>
</class>

<class id="info">
<div id="cityname" class="hidden">
This is where the content of the above link appears. It is just an info blurb,    
basically.
This js script works here. On the other page it does not. I believe I messed up 
somewhere in my classes...please help
</div>
</class>
</div>
```

The above code works **perfectly well** on a ["bare" php page](http://www.ialbania.com/hideunhide.php)

When I incorporate it into my main page, the js links no longer function. I believe i may have a mistake in my  arrangement (admittedly, classes and ids still confuse me).

[This is the page where the link appears, but does not work.](http://www.ialbania.com/cities.php)

Please help...

Comment: you should look at your javascript console for errors, when click you get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

Comment: You don't have an event which could "fire" the function, do you? Hover or click?

Comment: @djot he has inline javascript in the anchor tag

Comment: @patrick evans the problem is that I'm pretty new.  By "js console" I think "error log".  The code works perfectly fine on a standalone basis...

Comment: You should check your console logs. Also don't change the page if you have pasted a link as I see you have changed it to class names now - instead make a Fiddle.

Comment: @djot there's a few unhide statements in the inline...

Comment: @MatthewRiches I only changed the link wording on the main page to make it simpler to understand...sorry

Comment: Ok, if it fires ... ;) ... I hate JS.

Comment: @djot at the risk of going off topic, what alts do you use instead of JS for these sort of (little) scripts?

Comment: I avoid Javascript whenever possible - since decades - so don't ask me ;) ... (`onclick()` for plain JS or `jQuery.bind()`)

Comment: @djot Some people care about proper programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your "live" page you have redefined the function `unhide` with this code:

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName(divID)[0];
    console.log(item);
    console.log(item.className ==  divID + ' hide');
    if (item) {
    item.className = (item.className ==  divID + ' hide') ? divID + ' unhide' : divID + ' hide';
    }
}
```

If you remove, our comment out that code, everything works as expected.

Comment: It works, because I tested it by redefining the function back to its original state :)

Comment: you sir are a genius!!!! Much appreciated (FYI the code was a leftover from an earlier attempt at a hide/unhide js)

Comment: to understand the terminology, "redefining the function ..." means taking out the code above, right?  Again, thanks for your help! hattip

Comment: Redefining means defining again. You defined a function as so: `function foo(){}`, or `var foo = function(){}` or (the OOP way): `foo: function(){}`.